# Jquery Scrollbar while mouseover iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, mousewheel

Ok, so i am building a website at the moment. Got no issues with the html and serverside part of things.

However my javascript skills are a completely different story. Haven't worked with js for ages. What i'm trying to do is as followed. I have a div container called headcontent. In that container is contained my header, content and footer section. see link http://fenrir-multimedia.nl/dev/?slide=dunes# .

I am now trying to add a jquery based scrollbar called "Malihu custom content scroller". This replaces the normal scrollbar for a more sleek one. Issue is, my content section in this instance consists of an object or iframe, linking to another html document. Due to elaborate reasons i cannot put this content directly into the index.php file.

Now the scrollbar mostly works fine. Until i mouse over the object or iframe box. Then the mouse events are captured by the external document. And the scrolbar ceases to function.

My question is, is it possible to pass the mouseover information back to the parent document? This without drasticly messing arround with the .js file so friendly supplied by Malihu.gr.

Note: altho i stated it is an external document. It is actually running on the same server/domain. so i already know that this shouldnt pose an issue in regard to javascripts safety rules.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to capture the Left/Right commands when the user clicks out the scroll control.., am I right?

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
   //call scroll left on your control.
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
   //call scroll right 
  }
});
```

Comment: Not precisely. What i basicly want is to prevent the iframe from capturing the mouse events. So that when you scroll down the page it doesnt stop when the mousepointer hits the iframe. 

Wether i actually prevent the iframe from capturing the mouse events, or pass the events back to the parent document doesnt matter.

Comment: Also. i just found out the issue only arises when using Ie or firefox. Webkit seems to handle the page fine as it is.

Comment: I think i now understand what you mean. you think i want to be able to use the left/right text in the 2 corners to control the gallery. I got how you got that mixed up, my bad. 

I want jscript to completely disregard the iframe as an independent html file. But rather to see it as a part of the page.